# Adding Time to a DateTime object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to update a DateTime object with time of day. Here is what I'm currently trying to do:

```
time_of_day = schedule.start_at.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
specific_day_of_next_month(schedule.start_at) + time_of_day
```

the variable specific_day_of_next_month returns this value:

```
 => Thu, 27 Aug 2020 00:00:00 +0000
```

and time_of_day has this output.

```
 => "14:45:53"
```

So I'm basically trying to put them together.
But when I run that I get this error:

```
TypeError: expected numeric
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Is `schedule.start_at` a Time object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime#change`](https://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/change). Something like this:

```
time_arr = time_of_day.split(':')
h = {hour: time_arr[0].to_i, min: time_arr[1].to_i, sec:time_arr[2].to_i}

specific_day_of_next_month(schedule.start_at).change(h)
```

NOTE: I'm assuming `time_of_day` as string, like "14:45:53".

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'time'

dt = DateTime.new(2017, 8, 4)
time_to_add = "14:45:53"

hour, min, sec = time_to_add.split(":").map(&:to_i)
DateTime.new(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, hour, min, sec)
  #=> #<DateTime: 2017-08-04T14:45:53+00:00 ((2457970j,53153s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

or

```
(dt.to_time + [3600, 60, 1].zip(time_to_add.split(':')).
  reduce(0) { |tot,(sec,t)| tot + t.to_i*sec }).to_datetime 
  #=> #<DateTime: 2017-08-04T14:45:53+00:00 ((2457970j,53153s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```